# QuickBooks API throws exception com.intuit.apache.http.HttpRequest

Tags: api, quickbooks

I am using the QuickBooks Javav3SDK2.0.3 in a java web project and trying to get list of customers as given below, however I am getting the below exception. The API expects request of type com.intuit.apache.http.HttpRequest while it is passed the HttpServletRequest.

Code:

```
    OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new  OAuthAuthorizer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

        Context context = new Context(oauth, APP_TOKEN, ServiceType.QBO, COMPANY_ID);

        DataService service = new DataService(context);

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        List<Customer> customers = service.findAll(customer);

        Iterator itr = customers.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) 
        {
           Customer customer2 = (Customer) itr.next();
           String customerName = customer2.getFullyQualifiedName();
           System.out.println(customerName);
        }
```

Exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This consumer expects requests of type com.intuit.apache.http.HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code using the Javav3SDK2.0.3 and it worked fine for me. Are you sure every object you're using is from the same SDK? (2.0.3). My guess is whatever calls the authorize method on OAuthAuthorizer behind the scenes is passing in the HTTPServeletRequest instead of the com.intuit.apache.http.HttpRequest due to some sort of sdk version mismatch. I couldn't find any docs on the older quickbooks java sdk so I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your time Navey. Actually I have a very simple java web project and it contains only the Javav3SDK2.0.3 jars. So all of the classes are used from the same SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by installing MyEclipse 11 (Version: 2013 SR1) on another system (CentOS) while the previous system was Linux Fedora. Although I am still using jboss 7, however it works now. I don't know exactly how it got working, so no clue is available.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `.jar` you are using. If you check the `QuickBooks SDK`, you might be able to see that there are some jars with the name followed by "with dependencies".

For example `ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. If both this and the jar with out dependencies (in this case `ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2.jar`) are present at the same time, you might get the above error.

Remove the latter from the class path and you should be good to go.